# How is the empty string compared with other strings?

Tags: python, string

Comparing strings uses [lexigographical ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types). Lexicographical ordering for strings uses the Unicode code point number to order individual characters, but the empty string doesn't have any characters, so you can't do `ord('')`

So why is it that the empty string seems to be the "smallest" character?

```
l = ['1', '2', 'f', 'F', 'z', ' ', '+', '@', '-', '']
sorted(l)
#['', ' ', '+', '-', '1', '2', '@', 'F', 'f', 'z']
```

Comment: See the [ord documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord).  It works on a character, *not* on a string.

Comment: In Python there is no character type. So something like this 'a' *is* a string.
But yes, ord(s) work only when s contains exactly one character.

Comment: So is it safe to say that because the empty string `''` "begins" every python string, that the reason it is considered smaller is because "If one sequence is an initial sub-sequence of the other, the shorter sequence is the smaller (lesser) one."

Comment: Not exactly. When s1 is shorter than s2 it is possible to have s1 > s2.
For example : 'abc' < 'abcd' but 'adc' > 'azcd' because the first different character decide of the order of strings.

Comment: Try `[ord(c) for c in s]`. Or just `list(b)` if you start with a bytestring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ord(s)` returns the code of `s` only when `s` contains exactly one character. Other cases are no meaning and are incorrect.

The Python documentation of `ord()`:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord

For the lexicographic order you can see like this:

- `s1 == s2` if and only if s1 and s2 are exactly the same size and the
  same sequence of characters.
- Otherwise with `s1` and `s2` with the same
  beginning, such that `s1 == prefix + tail1` and `s2 == prefix + tail2`, with `tail1 != tail2`:

  - If `tail1` is empty then `s1 < s2`
  - If `tail2` is empty then `s1 > s2`
  - Else the order of the first character of `tail1` and the first character of `tail2` decide if `s1 < s2` or `s1 > s2`.

Thus, the empty string is the lowest of all.

Few examples:

- `'' < 'a'` because `tail1` is empty
- `'' < 'azerty'`  because `tail1` is empty
- `'abc' < 'abcd'` because `tail1` is empty
- `'abz' > 'abc'` because `'z' > 'c'`
- `'azc' > 'abcd'` because `'z' > 'b'`
- `'azc' > 'abc'` because `'z' > 'b'`
- `'abz' > 'abc'` because `'z' > 'c'`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. `ord()` returns the ASCII encoding of whatever character you put in there. If you check the ASCII encoding table, `''` is not in there. Thus, you passed an inappropriate type into `ord()` which will return TypeError as if you passed into multiple character at a time

Answer (score -2):

`ord` isn't used to compare strings. `<` is used instead by default if no `key` parameter is used as sorting function.

`ord` can only be used strings containing exactly 1 character to convert the only character of the string into its code.